# How to use Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First of all, where is the documentation for `Ajax.*` methods in asp.net mvc?

Can `Ajax.ActionLink` be used to call an action, get a partial view, open a modal window and put the content in it?

Comment: Here's the [MSDN documentation for Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Sure, a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861235/asp-net-mvc-modal-dialog-popup-best-practice) was asked before. Set the controller for ajax requests:

```
public ActionResult Show()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
    {
        return PartialView("Your_partial_view", new Model());
    }
    else 
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Set the action link as wanted:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show", 
                 "Show", 
                 null, 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", 
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                 UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id", 
                 OnComplete = "your_js_function();" })
```

Note that I'm using Razor view engine, and that your AjaxOptions may vary depending on what you want. Finally display it on a modal window. The [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is suggested.

Comment: you should also put "your_js_function()" in your answer.

Comment: What would I do in the case Where I want to use image as the anchor display instead of the word **show**?

Answer (score 45):

@Ajax.ActionLink requires jQuery AJAX Unobtrusive library. You can download it via nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

Then add this code to your View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Comment: This was the key point I don't find in the other documentation.

Comment: @Rozwel I couldn't find it anywhere either. What an obscure "gotcha". Tip for Microsoft: don't do this.

Comment: do this first , add this nugget package even if you are in VS 2017, this issue exists, we have to manually add this package to the project for anything with @Ajax to work in your cshtml

Comment: Well, +1 for this as all answers failed to add this key point about the Library.

Answer (score 9):

For me this worked after I downloaded  AJAX Unobtrusive library via NuGet :

```
 Search and install via NuGet Packages:   Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

Than add in the view the references to jquery and AJAX Unobtrusive:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ajax.ActionLink only sends an ajax request to the server. What happens ahead really depends upon type of data returned and what your client side script does with it. You may send a partial view for ajax call or json, xml etc. Ajax.ActionLink however have different callbacks and parameters that allow you to write js code on different events. You can do something before request is sent or `onComplete`. similarly you have an onSuccess callback. This is where you put your JS code for manipulating result returned by server. You may simply put it back in UpdateTargetID or you can do fancy stuff with this result using jQuery or some other JS library.