# ASP.NET MVC using Ajax.ActionLink to make changes in database

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been searching for informations on how to use AJAX in MVC projects and so far it just confused me a bit. I belive I'm not too far now to implement an Ajax ActionLink that causes a database entry to change and so this change gets reflected to the view. But clearly, this bit of code is wrong right now:

```
public void MarkAsRead(Models.MessageModel message)
    {
        using (var db = new MessengerDBEntities())
        {
            var dbMessage = db.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.messageID == message.Id);

            // Error handling
            if (dbMessage == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ResultMessage =
                    "Something bad has happened with that message in the meantime. Please log out and in again.";
                return;
            }

            dbMessage.messageRead = true;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return;
        }
    }
```

This is the Razor code:

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
<br /><br />

string messageClass;
foreach (var message in Model)
{
    messageClass = message.Read ? "message-header" : "message-unread-header";

    <div class="message-container">
        <div class="@messageClass">
            @if (!message.Read)
            {
                <text>New </text>
            }

            From: @message.Sender 

            @if(!message.Read)
            {
                <span class="mark-read-span">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Mark as read", "MarkAsRead", message, new AjaxOptions())
                </span>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="message-mainbody">
            @message.Content
        </div>

        <div class="message-footer">
            At: @message.Timestamp.ToShortDateString() @message.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString()
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
}
}
else
{
    <div id="no-messages-div">You haven't got any messages yet. :(</div>
}
```

In the view, I'm iterating through a collection of objects (received messages). For each message, I check if it has been read yet, and if it's not, there goes a link that tilt it to read state. I also assign a different class to the div that shows the message based on wheather it's a new message or not:

```
@messageClass = message.Read ? "message-header" : "message-unread-header";

    <div class="message-container">
        <div class="@messageClass">
    ...
```

I'm suspecting that I use the Ajax.ActionLink helper with wrong AjaxOptions parameter, but I didn't get closer to the solution after reading MSDN about it.
What could I do wrong with this?

Comment: show your complete view please

Comment: View is too long to a comment, edited question.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586327/how-to-use-ajax-actionlink

Comment: I've found that post early on and wasn't too helpful for me. I can't use the UpdateTargetId parameter (maybe different razor version?) and I'm not sure if I should use it at all.
But is my MarkAsRead method correct at least? Is it ok to return a void for that?

Comment: Use the ajax options and define the POST method

Comment: The POST method was missing, indeed. Thank you for pointing hat out! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is, try to use the ID of the messages.

You should know that in MVC route is defined as Controller/Action/id

So, if you pass the ID of the message to the Action then you can change the message status in the Database.
For example:

```
public ActionResult Message(long messageid)
{
    // do you stuff to the message here in the database
    // then return view or partial view whatever you want
    return View();
}
```

The correct syntax for the Ajax.ActionLink function call it:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("You Link Name", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { ID = @Message.ID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "update-div-ID", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

In the above call, I was returning a partial view and displaying that in Div with ID "update-div-ID". You need to take care of AjaxOptions like this.