# Ajax with MVC Partial Views - Ajax.ActionLink not working, while jQuery does

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render partial view with Ajax to fill the `<div id="AjaxDiv"></div>` element. I'm able to achieve this with jQuery:

```
<input id="btnCompetitors" type="button" value="Get Competitors" />

<script>
        function loadCategoriesPartialView() {
            $('#AjaxDiv').load(@Url.Action("CategoriesPartial", "Dashboard"));
        }
    </script>
```

but I cannot get it to work with Ajax.ActionLink, which I would prefer.

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Categories", "CategoriesPartial", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "AjaxDiv",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
```

What is missing? I tried various additional AjaxOptions, like calling the same method with OnSuccess etc., but I cannot do it properly. Bundles work fine for jquery (basically jquery + unobtrusiveAjax), so hopefully the same ones should work for the Ajax helper.

Comment: Why would you prefer Ajax.ActionLink over jQuery?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586327/how-to-use-ajax-actionlink

Comment: I'm not skilled enough with jQuery itself

Comment: @Gene R - I did check this one

Comment: Do you get any javascript error?

Comment: Have you included `jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`  `js`?? `Ajax.ActionLink` can not work without this `js`

Comment: Can you include your `Controller` code also?

Comment: Controller is super basic. public ActionResult CategoriesPartial {return PartialView("_Categories")}; it does not matter what is in _Categories, this issue is the same. unobtrusive ajax is installed and referrenced in bundles.

Comment: I need to check the js console for errors - I did not do it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I overlooked the issue, and helpers were rendering correctly. It's jQuery that was wrong. Below the correct one:

```
<input id="btnCategories" type="button" value="Get Categories" />

<div id="AjaxDiv"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnCategories").click(function () {
            $("#AjaxDiv").load("@Url.Action("CategoriesPartial", "Dashboard")");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

data model

```
public class DisplayData
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public DisplayData(int ID)
   {
          this.ID = ID;
   }
}
```

Main View(PartialDemo.cshtml)

```
  @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication5.Models.DisplayData>        
  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "PartialDemo";
   }
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Click 1", "PartialDemo", "PartialDemo", new {Data= "1" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "rsvpmsg" })
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Click 2", "PartialDemo", "PartialDemo", new {Data= "2" }, new  AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "rsvpmsg" })

 <div id="rsvpmsg">
       @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialDemoUC", this.Model);}
 </div>
```

Create a Partial view `PartialDemoUC.cshtml`

```
model IEnumerable<dynamic> 

@foreach(var items in Model)
{
   @items.ID   
}
```

Action Method

1)This will be called the first when you render the view and the time when you press the ajax button

```
 public ActionResult PartialDemo(string Data)
    {
       List<DisplayData> Display = new List<DisplayData>();

       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {
          if (Data == "1")
          {
             Display.Add(new DisplayData(3));
             Display.Add(new DisplayData(4));
          }
          else
          {
            Display.Add(new DisplayData(5));
            Display.Add(new DisplayData(6));
          }
          return PartialView("PartialDemoUC",Display);
       }
       else
       {
           Display.Add(new DisplayData(1));
           Display.Add(new DisplayData(2));
           return View("PartialDemo", Display);
       }
    }
```

Comment: this is much more than I want to achieve here. I want to pass the model to partial views, not to the index view that includes these partial views. But I see interestingly apart from unobtrusive-ajax, you also reference unobtrusive itself. I will try this.