# Showing details of an item Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

In my main View I have a foreach loop that loops through all my patients

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach (var patient in Model.Patients)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.FirstName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.LastName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.PersonalID)</td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Edit</a>
                                <a onclick="showDetails()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Detail</a>
                                <form asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

If I add another `<div></div>`

```
<div class="col-9 detailPatient" style="color:black;">
            @foreach (var doctor in Model.Doctors)
            {
                if (doctor.Id == patient.Id) <--------------- How do I get this patient.Id when someone clicks on the Details button. Do I need a partial View?
                {
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.FirstName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.LastName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.GodineIskustva)</td>
                }
            }
        </div>
```

after the `</tbody>` tag, how can I when desplay item details that are associated with my `@patient.Id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render partial view with in Main view on link clicking in MVC..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754236/how-to-render-partial-view-with-in-main-view-on-link-clicking-in-mvc)

Comment: @SelimYıldız Is there any chance you could show me how to implement that in my code? I've been trying the solution that you linked but it hasn't been working.

Comment: I have added an answer and tried to explain how it works, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load details with using [`PartialView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial). Here is the full example of how it works:

First, you need to create new partial view:

```
@foreach (var doctor in Model.Doctors)
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.FirstName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.LastName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => doctor.GodineIskustva)</td>
}
```

In controller I assume you have method that retrieves doctors by patient:

```
// GET: Doctor/DetailsByPatientId/5
public ActionResult DetailsByPatientId(int id)
{
    List<Doctor> doctors = new List<Doctor>()
    {
        new Doctor(){ FirstName ="doctor 1"},
        new Doctor(){ FirstName ="doctor 2"}
    };
    return PartialView("_DoctorsByPatient", doctors);
}
```

And finally in your main Patient view, pass `PatientId` to `showDetail` function:

```
<a onclick="showDetails(@patient.PersonalID);" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Detail</a>
```

Then load partial view with JQuery:

```
function showDetails(patientId) {
    $('.detailPatient').load("/Doctor/DetailsByPatientId/" + patientId);
}
```

See these references for more information:

- [How to render partial view with in Main view on link clicking in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754236/how-to-render-partial-view-with-in-main-view-on-link-clicking-in-mvc)
- [Render Partial View Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: This works great! For anyone using this code in the future, make sure you're returning the right type of ViewModel from the controller. Thank you Selim!