# How to render partial view when the model comes from the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a controller which returns a list of object, i need to display it to a partialview. So what I want is that the partial view inside the non partial view will accept the result and not the non partial view.

This is the "NON" partial view named "Index"

**My table headers are here:**

```
<tbody>
     @Html.RenderPartial()
     Action("DashboardSearchResult","Dashboard",new { List<ReservationType> reservationList})
</tbody>
```

**This is my partial view named "_Dashboard"**

```
@model IEnumerable<HotelOrganization.Models.ReservationType>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationId)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationStartDate)</td>
<tr>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public PartialViewResult DashboardSearchResult(List<ReservationType>reservationList)
{
return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Dashboard", reservationList);
}
```

Comment: Use div id and load it on click event of button            $("#Grid").load("../Controller/Action")

Comment: Hi.I think that you should use something like that.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586327/how-to-use-ajax-actionlink).Let me give you brief, explain.If you want to load your data on-demand and don't reload all page use ajax request to your controller.

Comment: Its `@Html.Action("DashboardSearchResult","Dashboard",new {  reservationList = yourListofReservationType })` (not clear where you list comes from - does you model have a property for it?)

Comment: never mind people, i asked the answer already and corrected my mistake, thanks for all the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can Render the partial Action Directly inside your .cshtml code like this

```
@Html.RenderAction Or @Html.Action
```

You can also use @pathik suggestion but it will send one more request to do same thing.