# Open a view as a pop up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Controller.cs is:

```
 public ActionResult ViewRequest(int id)
        {
            Job job = Jobs.GetJob(id);

            return View(job);
        }
```

It's view is:

```
@model model.Job
<fieldset>
    <legend>Job</legend>


    <div class="display-label">Name</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

</fieldset>
    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = model.Id }) |
```

**How do I open it as a model pop up**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a class to the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = model.Id }, 
                                         new{ @class = "dialog"} )
```

And add this script somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('a.dialog').click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
            dialog.load(url, {}, 
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({
                    close: function(event, ui) {
                        dialog.remove();
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Required CSS/JS**

- jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Hi, I tried the code but I got the following error:
TypeError: dialog.dialog is not a function
would you please help me?

Comment: Have you loaded included jQueryUI?

Comment: That's the only reason that I can think of. Double check that it's included,. It must be included in the parent view and not the one that you need to load in dialog.

Comment: Thanks of you'r consideration, My codes are as following:
html:
 @Html.ActionLink("Create Personnel", "Create", "Personnel", null, new {@class = "btn btn-success dialog", returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl })

Comment: I bundled JqueryUi and some others, and rendered them in my parent layout

Comment: which js and css are required?

Answer (score 9):

You could append the `target="_blank"` HTML attribute to the anchor if you want the url to be opened in a new browser window:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "view request in a new window", 
    "ViewRequest", 
    new { id = model.Id }, 
    new { target = "_blank" }
)
```

Or if you want to open it in a new modal window you could use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) widget you could unobtrusively AJAXify this link (after applying it an unique id):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "view request in a new window", 
    "ViewRequest", 
    new { id = model.Id }, 
    new { id = "linkId" }
)
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#linkId').click(function() {
        $.get(this.href, function(result) {  
            $(result).dialog();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

or if you want to open the dialog immediately when the link is clicked and provide a small feedback while the AJAX call executes:

```
$(function() {
    $('#linkId').click(function() {
        $('<div>Loading ...</div>').load(this.href).dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
```