# Inserting a functional strongly-typed create view in a modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a menu item on my site, which should open a create view wherever I am in the site. The view inserts basic properties into my database's tables. This is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@model ITS.Models.Server
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <div title="boo, this is a popup">Get that pop-up
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddServer", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add a new server</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server_Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Server_Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Name)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My controllers are fairly simple:

```
public ActionResult AddServer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddServer([Bind(Include = "Server_Name")] Server @server)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Servers.Add(@server);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return PartialView(@server);
        }
```

First of all, is it possible? I want to be able to insert my values through a model after all. 
I tried at least to visualize it in the popup with the answer from this article, but with no success: 
[Open a view as a pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064875/open-a-view-as-a-pop-up)
It opens the popup with no content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of grief and use a Javascript library like jQuery UI, or ExtJS, or Kendo.  All have extensive documentation that make the Javascript and CSS parts of rendering the dialog quite painless.  There's little need to write your own code when there are these libraries that have been tested and "blessed" by the masses already.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, since the modal popups (that I'm trying to use) are a part of jQuery UI? Did you read my question thoroughly?